# How to Import Data from SAP using wsdl file and also how to consume the proxy class generated from it

Tags: asp.net-core, soap, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

Can somebody please explain me how to use the proxy class as I don't understand it, also I have an Interface in the proxy class how should I implement it to access the method described in IBinding

The generated code for the proxy class is as given below:

```
public interface IBinding {

/// <remarks/>
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://sap.com/xi/A1S/Global/QueryProjectIn/FindProjectByElementsRequest", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProjectByElementsResponse_sync", Namespace="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global")]
ProjectByElementsResponseMessage_sync FindProjectByElements([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global")] ProjectByElementsQueryMessage_sync ProjectByElementsQuery);
```

}

```
 [HttpGet]
    public static void Main()
    {
        ProjectByElementsQuerySelectionByElements query = new 
        ProjectByElementsQuerySelectionByElements();
        ProjectByElementsQueryMessage_sync sync = new 
        ProjectByElementsQueryMessage_sync
        {
        ProjectSelectionByElements = query

        };

    
}
```

Comment: I have recently made changes to the question I previously asked and would like to know more about SOAP based implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to create a web reference :
Visual Studio -> Add Service Reference -> paste the wsdl document path in your local machine -> click  Go

A service will be visible as per the wsdl and the corresponding methods can be seen by clicking on the service name then in Advanced section a web service button is available, make a web reference by writing the name of the web reference and click on the button a web reference will automatically be added to the project.

Instantiate the reference file and access the method
for connection :

```
using webreference;
var service = new service();
        service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        service.Url = "https://" + xxx.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you access an SAP system since the data is typically not stored in just one table and it would circumvent any authorization checks that are available in the application framework.
So you should look for appropriate API's as you can find them on the API Hub.

Comment: Api hub link please? Also what about .Net connector https://support.sap.com/content/dam/support/en_us/library/ssp/products/connectors/msnet/dotnet_connector_30_programming_guide.pdf